# Does `File.info(string)/File::Info.new(string)` resolve symbolic links?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm using Crystal 0.25.0 and `File.info(string).symlink?` returns false when it should return true in the following sample:

```
`mkdir -p /tmp/delete`
 Dir.cd "/tmp/delete"
`rm -f b`
`touch a`
`ln -s a b`

puts File.info("b").symlink?.inspect  # false
puts File.info("b").type              # File
puts Process.run("test", "-L b".split).success? # true
puts Process.run("test", "-L a".split).success? # false
```

It seems to resolve the link. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `File.info` follows symlinks by default. This is the expected behavior, but you can disable it by passing `follow_symlinks: false` to the method:

```
File.info("b", follow_symlinks: false).symlink? # => true
```

This behavior is documented under [`File.info`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/File.html#info%28path%2Cfollow_symlinks%3Dtrue%29%3AInfo-class-method) in the API docs.

Comment: Thanks. I kept looking at `File::Info.new`. I forgot to look at `File.info`. My mistake.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's an easy thing to miss. `File::Info` is an abstract struct that you as a developer will most likely not want to use. It can be used by various archive library implementations like the `.tar`-format to provide an `File::Info` to the user of an in-memory archive without needing to write the data to disk and then rely on the OS to provide it (like linux provides `stat`). Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the `File::Info` instance for anything else, you can just use [`File.symlink?`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.0/File.html#symlink?(path):Bool-class-method) which essentially calls `info(path, follow_symlinks: false).symlink?`.